# SFML Include Issues

Tags: c++, sfml, visual-studio

I'm trying to copy over a VS2017 solution/project which uses SFML to a different machine. On the original machine, everything compiles and runs fine however when copied over to the second machine (which has a freshly downloaded version of VS2017 with most of the useful add-ons), I'm getting "Cannot open include file: 'SFML\Graphics.hpp'", etc.

I've checked the project properties and everything appears to be the same as its working counterpart.

Comment: Are the library files located at the same place on both machines? When you check the properties, are you sure you check for the right build (release/debug)?

Comment: Everything is contained in the solution folder.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt, although I've noticed that the External Dependencies folder is completely empty...

Comment: A thing to check: in VS properties of the project, _Configuration Properties_ > _C/C++_ > _Command Line_, inspect that long string. If you don't see the root where the folder of SFML is located, then you know you missed something. I would simply add it to the _C/C++_ > _General_ > _Additional Include Directories_ property.

Comment: It's a bit hard to debug that kind of issue on sites such as this one.

Comment: This should probably be a comment but as I cant do that... I recently noticed when copying an .sln file that it keeps a full path to dependencies and files. So even if SFML has the same relative path it may not be able to find it.